# Can you have two paths listed in init.d file?

Tags: init.d

In `/etc/init.d/red5` can I list two home paths for different programs using it that are in different locations?

I have red5 set up in /var/www/html

but I also have it set up in /var/www/html/red5/webapps

At the moment I am  using `service red5 start` in the first and in second directory `sh red5.sh`. I know they do the same thing except with the first it shuts down on command `service red5 stop` but on the second it never wants to shut down, at least not right away with `./red5-shutdown.sh`

The bash script seems more efficient and so I wondered if I could use it for both?

Comment: Well it works. I just copied the file and renamed it red and so when i go to start othr program i can just command service red start - I am having to do this because openmeetings is confusing for me to get working in with other red5 apps! Directory wise- I seem to have great difficulty with directory structures!!

Comment: perhaps the general consensus is this is a stupid or redundant question but it has lessened a headache for me. :)